# floating-point number stored in float variable has other value

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm reading a book about C programming By "King.K.N" and I'm reading the following statement:

> If we store 0.1 in a float variable, we may later find that the variable has a value such as 0.0999999999999999987

But I can't understand why float type variable may have different value?

Answer (score 6):

You *try* to store decimal 0.1 in a float variable. When we talk about float in C (and in most other languages), [numbers according to IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) are meant.

Float numbers are stored in base 2, and 1/10 cannot be converted to a binary fraction in a lossless way.

Think of how you try to store 1/3 in base 10: You end up with `0.33333`. But `3 * 0.33333` is not equal to `1`, but to `0.99999`.

For more details, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: For a somewhat easier introduction: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Why we can't store 0.1 into binary format? 1/10 doesn't give us infinite numbers after decimal point.

Comment: @Higgs yes 0.1 in base 10 is fine but in base 2 it is not fine base10(0.1)=base2(0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100...) and never ends. So in a finite direct storage it will always be approximated. It is possible to store numbers in BCD (binary coded decimal) even if they are fractionary, but it is not done because 1) it is a waste of space 2) it will be slower to calculate.

Comment: @Higgs 5 is not a divisor of 2, so 1/10 = 1/(2*5) cannot be stored in a finite binary fraction.